# I can not download a blob from GAE BlobStore

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, blobstore

What is wrong with this code? I can not download a blob following the download url sent as response of the UploadHandler. I am getting a 404 response from the server.
I have doubts about how to send an url safe version of the blob key.

```
import urllib
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

MAIN = """<html>
<body>
   <form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <p>Upload File:<input type="file" name="file"></p>
       <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
   </form>
</body>
</html>
"""

DOWNLOAD = """<html><body><p><a href="%s">%s</a></p></body></html>"""

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        self.response.out.write(MAIN % upload_url)

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is name field in the form
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        _key = blob_info.key()
        _url = '/download/%s' % str(_key)
        _url_text = blob_info.filename
        self.response.out.write(DOWNLOAD % (_url, _url_text))

class DownloadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        blob_info = blobstore.Blob.get(resource)
        self.sendblob(blob_info)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                               ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                               ('/download/<resource>', DownloadHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

app.yaml file is
    application: georef
    version: 1
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: false

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: georef.app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you copy and pasted the code wrong from the docs:

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

You're missing the line to unencode the resource string in case it has any strange characters in it.

Comment: It is true that I wrote the code reading the docs [https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers#BlobstoreUploadHandler](docs), and I left out the lines with the urllib calls. However, I have noticed in your answer that i mispelled send_blob (I have written sendblob in my code). So, the DownloadHandler is not executed. Besides the urllib quote and unquote calls, there are another troubles I dont know.

Comment: You'd be better off adding some log statements to debug and ensure the right values (like `resource`) are being passed around.  You also want to use the blobstore viewer in admin to make sure your blob was actually uploaded.